# How can I add my own company logo when sharing an URL or searching for my website on Google?

Tags: urls, logo

I'm trying to add my logo to my website (not to the actual website, but more for SEO purposes when sharing a link to the website).

I would like to have my own logo whenever I share a link to the website. At the moment, it is showing a WordPress logo.

[image]

I hope someone can help me out. Thank you!

Comment: When you say sharing, how exactly are you sharing this? Is wherever you're putting this fetching the WordPress oEmbed block? I didn't think that had an estimated reading time.

Comment: And do you have a favicon set on your site? It might be using that, and that's the WordPress logo by default.